# Goroutine execution order

Tags: go, concurrency, goroutine

I'm a beginner of golang and I'm learning the goroutine and channel. Intuitively, I consider a gorountine in golang is essentially a thread running independently. Therefore, if there are more than one goroutine, the execution order won't be guaranteed. Hence, the following code should output "ping" and "pong" in a random order. However, what I observed is that the program yields "ping" and "pong" in turn. Can anyone explain the reason for me? Any reply would be helpful. Thanks!

Another intriguing observation I found is that if I don't call sleep function inside the printer function, the program will output in a random order.

```
package main

import (
  "fmt"
  "time"
)

func pinger(c chan string) {
  for i := 0; ; i++ {
    c <- "ping"
  }
}

func printer(c chan string) {
  for {
    msg := <- c
    fmt.Println(msg)
    time.Sleep(time.Second * 1)
  }
}

func ponger(c chan string) {
  for i := 0; ; i++ {
    c <- "pong"
  }
}

func main() {
  var c chan string = make(chan string)

  go pinger(c)
  go ponger(c)
  go printer(c)

  var input string
  fmt.Scanln(&input)
}
```

Answer (score 4):

> [The Go Programming Language Specification](https://golang.org/ref/spec)
>
> [Channel types](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Channel_types)
>
> The capacity, in number of elements, sets the size of the buffer in
>   the channel. If the capacity is zero or absent, the channel is
>   unbuffered and communication succeeds only when both a sender and
>   receiver are ready.

---

You have an unbuffered channel: `make(chan string)`.

`msg := <- c` (ready to receive) and  `c <- "ping"` (ready to send): send and receive `"ping"`.

`msg := <- c` (ready to receive) and  `c <- "pong"` (ready to send): send and receive `"pong"`.

Answer (score 3):

To better understand consider the following statement and demo program:

1. Sends on a blocked channel will be serviced in order of attempted send.  I wasn't 100% sure about this but the demo program shows this behavior and this [ticket][1] mentions implementing this behavior over 2 years ago.

To really see this you should run this on your machine:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    count := 10
    c := make(chan int)
    for i := 0; i < count; i++ {
        go func(i int) {
            c <- i + 1
        }(i)
    }
    for i := 0; i < count; i++ {
        fmt.Println("c", <-c)
    }

    fmt.Println()

    d := make(chan int)
    for i := 0; i < count; i++ {
        go func(i int) {
            d <- i + 1
        }(i)
        time.Sleep(time.Millisecond * 5)
    }
    for i := 0; i < count; i++ {
        fmt.Println("d", <-d)
    }

    var input string
    fmt.Scanln(&input)
}
```

Here is a playground, though it won't be as obvious what is happening because the first group (`c`) will always appear in a consistent (though non-sorted) order.  The second group (`d`) will always appear in order on the playground or locally.

https://play.golang.org/p/JCVyVlFPRXS

These are the outputs from 3 runs locally

```
 1     2     3
----------------
c 2   c 10  c 10
c 1   c 4   c 2
c 6   c 1   c 1
c 3   c 2   c 4
c 4   c 3   c 3
c 5   c 7   c 5
c 8   c 5   c 8
c 7   c 6   c 7
c 9   c 8   c 9
c 10  c 9   c 6

d 1   d 1   d 1
d 2   d 2   d 2
d 3   d 3   d 3
d 4   d 4   d 4
d 5   d 5   d 5
d 6   d 6   d 6
d 7   d 7   d 7
d 8   d 8   d 8
d 9   d 9   d 9
d 10  d 10  d 10
```